# add timestamp when specific cell = "complete"

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following script that will add a timestamp to column 11 when column 4 in the same row and sheet is changed.
I now want to charge it so that it only charges when the text "Complete" is what is added to column 4

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if(col === 4 && row > 4 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() ==="Sheet1" ) {
    
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,11).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var value = e.range.getValue();
if(col === 4 && row > 4 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() ==="Sheet1" && value === "Complete") {.....
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that it will only add the timestamp if the cell in column 11 is already black, but is something in the cell already it leaves it as is?

Comment: I assume you mean 'blank' instead of black? 
In that case, add an if statement. 
var destination = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,11);
if (destination.getValue() == "") {destination.setValue(new Date());}